# lme4 and languageR compatibility error: "input model is not a mer object”

Tags: r, lme4

I have a dataset dat2 on which I want to fit a linear mixed-effects model. I used lmer() (package lme4) in the past in complement of pvals.fnc to compute the associated p-values.

However, since I reinstalled R 3.0.2 version with the new lme4 (1.0.4) and languageR (1.4) packages I obtain an error about the output of lmer function. It says that the output is not a mer object. Indeed its class is lmeRmod.

Here is the code I use:

```
names(dat2)<-c("auc","subj","decod","soa","vis")
attach(dat2)
mod1 <- lmer(auc ~ decod + (1 | subj))
mod2 <- lmer(auc ~ vis+ (1 | subj))
mod3 <- lmer(auc ~ decod + vis + (1 | subj))
mod4 <- lmer(auc ~ decod + vis + decod*vis + (1 | subj))
pvals.fnc(mod1)
```

And I get this error:

```
> pvals.fnc(mod1)
the input model is not a mer object
NULL
```

Indeed, when I look at mod1, I find it is a lmeRmod object and not a mer object.

```
> mod1
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: auc ~ decod + (1 | subj) 
REML criterion at convergence: -213.3884 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 subj     (Intercept) 0.04187 
 Residual             0.11087 
Number of obs: 155, groups: subj, 6
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)       decod2       decod3       decod4  
     0.9798      -0.1141      -0.3599      -0.3090
```

This problem is very similar to the one discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046076/languager-error-input-model-is-not-a-mer-object). Any ideas of 1/ what the problem might be (why do I do not output a mer object) and 2/ how to work around it (I tried reinstalling older versions but I have compatibility problems between packages) ?

Any help would be great !
thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that the `pvals.fnc` function doesn't work in the new `languageR` -- this is essentially because `mcmcsamp` wasn't implemented in the new version of `lme4`, which in turn because it was found to be unreliable in many cases.

We (the `lme4` authors) are sorry to have left `languageR` users in the lurch this way, but it was somewhat unavoidable.

https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/man/pvalues.Rd offers some alternative suggestions for what to do about computing p-values.

https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/man/drop1.merMod.Rd gives a particular recipe (for the development version of `lme4`) about how to use `pbkrtest::KRmodcomp` to get p-values for all of the predictors in a model:

```
 fm1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
 ## Likelihood ratio test
 drop1(fm1,test="Chisq")
 if (require(pbkrtest)) {
    KRSumFun <- function(object, objectDrop, ...) {
       krnames <- c("ndf","ddf","Fstat","p.value","F.scaling")
       r <- if (missing(objectDrop)) {
           setNames(rep(NA,5),krnames)
       } else {
          krtest <- KRmodcomp(object,objectDrop)
          unlist(krtest$stats[krnames])
       }
       attr(r,"method") <- c("Kenward-Roger via pbkrtest package")
       r
    }
    drop1(fm1,test="user",sumFun=KRSumFun)
}
```

This example produces:

```
Single term deletions

Model:
Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
Method: 
Kenward-Roger via pbkrtest package


       ndf ddf  Fstat    p.value F.scaling
<none>                                    
Days     1  17 45.853 3.2638e-06         1
```

Comment: This does not appear to work in the currently distributed version of lme4 (lme4_1.0-5) as the drop1.merMod method is:

*1 - Still hidden by the drop1 version in the stats package for some reason     
*2 - Looking at lme4:::drop1.merMod shows that the method only takes the following parameters for test: 

test = c("none", "Chisq")

so it throws an error.  

Do you know when the new version on github will be updated to CRAN?

Comment: No, but version 1.1-2 should be available via: `install.packages("lme4",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")`.  Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Package ‘lmerTest’ to get the p_values. 
See the example below:

```
#import lme4 package and lmerTest package
library(lmerTest)
# an object of class merModLmerTest
m <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ Gender+Information+Product +(1|Consumer), data=ham)
# gives summary of lmer object. The same as of class merMod but with
# additional p-values calculated based on Satterthwate's approximations
summary(m)
```

More about Package ‘lmerTest’, please see the link below:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/lmerTest.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You might look into the mixed function in the afex package found [here](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/afex/html/mixed.html). It uses Kenward-Rogers for df.

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."